# Can use visual studio 2017 with angular4 whitout index view? without mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular, asp.net-core-mvc, visual-studio-2017

All the examples I've seen, even the "official examples" (spa) all use an MVC project always having a view (index.cshtml) to run a project using angular (2/4).

Angular is a front-end framework that does not need a view (index.cshtml) to fulfill its function, the concept of front-end is to develop everything next to the client without depending on the backend.

Then, because you have to use a server-side view to work the client side.

What would be the best way to work with an application using angular (2/4)? Of course it would be better to use a single solution for all projects, but i see that can't separate the front end with back end.

Comment: There are actually quite a few examples of using Angular with ASP.Net WebAPI, where the only server elements are API endpoints, and the angular app is served from a static directory.  Unfortunately, locating those examples for you would make the answer (and technically the question) off topic, as this site does not deal in 3rd party site recommendations.

Comment: Many of the .NET devs I know are using the Angular CLI and an editor such as VS Code for the Angular piece, and only using Visual Studio 2017 for the back-end piece. That may be an option for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your's answers. I'm start to configurate angular cli with vsCode, when finished the course in pluralsight "Implementing and Securing an API with ASP.NET Core" i will create the api proyect..